# Cache manager with Spring Data Redis 2.0.3

Tags: redis, spring-data-redis

Currently, I'm using spring cache by using @Cachable with Ehcache. I'm about to replace Ehcache with Redis by using Spring Data Redis 2.0.3. All examples I see on the web are based on the old versions of it but the new version has the different format of constructors.

This is my current cacheManager conf:

```
<bean id="ehcache" class="org.springframework.cache.ehcache.EhCacheManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="configLocation" value="classpath:ehcache.xml"/>
    <property name="shared" value="true"/>
</bean>
```

The example of using Redis based on the older version is:

```
<bean id="cacheManager" class="org.springframework.data.redis.cache.RedisCacheManager"
        c:template-ref="redisTemplate" />
```

The constructor in the new version is totally different from the older versions and all examples of the new version put everything into cache manually like this:

```
redisTemplate.opsForHash().put(user.getObjectKey(), user.getKey(), user);
```

I still want to use cacheManager and `@cachable` but have no idea how to configure the `cacheManager` bean with the new version of Spring Data Redis. The constructor of the new versions needs RedisCacheWriter:

```
 public RedisCacheManager(RedisCacheWriter cacheWriter, RedisCacheConfiguration defaultCacheConfiguration)
```

I appreciate if you can share your idea about how to set up `cacheManager` to use `@Cachable` with the new version of Spring Data Redis(min 2.0.3).

Answer (score 0):

In Spring Data Redis 2.0+,you could write like this:

```
/**
 * Redis config.
 *
 * @author chenxinyu
 */
@Configuration
@EnableCaching
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.host}")
    private String redisHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.port}")
    private Integer redisPort;

    @Bean
    public JedisConnectionFactory jedisConnectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration configuration =
                new RedisStandaloneConfiguration(redisHost, redisPort);
        return new JedisConnectionFactory(configuration);
    }

    @Bean(name = "redisTemplate")
    public RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisSerializer genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer = new GenericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer();
        RedisSerializer stringRedisSerializer = new StringRedisSerializer();

        RedisTemplate<Object, Object> redisTemplate = new RedisTemplate<>();

        redisTemplate.setKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setHashKeySerializer(stringRedisSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setValueSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setHashValueSerializer(genericJackson2JsonRedisSerializer);
        redisTemplate.setConnectionFactory(factory);

        return redisTemplate;
    }

    @Bean
    public CacheManager initRedisCacheManager(RedisConnectionFactory factory) {
        RedisCacheManager.RedisCacheManagerBuilder builder = RedisCacheManager
                .RedisCacheManagerBuilder.fromConnectionFactory(factory);
        return builder.build();
    }

}
```

this is just one example, you can see more methods in `RedisCacheManager.java`.

Comment: Where are you making use of Redis Template here ?